# can I change the shape of line of mkpolylineview?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mapkit, polyline, mkoverlay

I wonder if I can have directed arrow line instead of straight line in mkpolyline view.

I am using these lines as overlays. Can anyone please tell my how to have an arrow line as overlay?

Do I need to subclass mkpolyline or mkoverlay for this?
I am not sure what to do...
Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think you can do something like as that there is no property available to set this. At max you can have title and subtitle to your polylines.